# Automatically adjusting plot limits when adding text to matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

When I add text to a matplotlib plot which is outside the current limits of the axes, the axes do not adjust and the text will be outside the axes of the plot. Is there a way for me to (almost) automatically adjust the limits of the axes so that the text falls inside the axes?

Here is a minimal (non-)working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 2, 4, 1, 5])
plt.text(5, 3, "This text goes outside the plot.")
plt.text(3, 6, "This text is entirely outside the plot.")
plt.show()
```

[image: A plot with the issues described above.]

The minimal example is of course artificial, and could be solved manually. In my real situation:

- The process is repeated several times on different data. It is repeated often enough that I do not want to manually figure out good limits for each case.
- The placement of the text is meaningful and based on the data, so it does not make sense to move the text to a spot within the axes -- I need to change the axes to fit the text.

**Note:** This by itself would be less of a problem, but I am in particular using matplotlib in combination with Jupyter notebooks and the `%matplotlib notebook` command, where the visible part of the plot is restricted to the part within the axes (with some padding). As a result, the two text lines added above are cut off or not visible at all.

[image: Plot with issues described above.]

I feel like these are two separate questions, though, so it might not be appropriate to deal with both issues in one question; and if I can solve the former question, I think the latter will be solved too.

Comment: I would agree to this being a duplicate, however did you consider placing the text in a way that if would not ever overflow the axes, e.g. right adjust to the right axes spine?

Comment: Calling tight_layout or using constrianed_layout will make the annotation visible, but will shrink the size of the parent axes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
axes.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
```

to set the limits of your axes. If these limits are stored as variables, you can then set your text to be relative to those variables. For example, if you set:

```
xmax, ymax = 10, 10
```

Then you can set your text to be in a position like `xmax - 2` and `ymax - 2`.

This will make your plot larger and guarantee the text is inside.

If you don't know what size you want the plot to be (e.g. you don't know the limits of your data), you could find the max values of your data automatically (with `max()`); add a little bit so the plot is larger than it needs to be; then do the above.

Comment: I am indeed in the situation where I do not know in advance what my data will be (or rather, I want to repeat this process for lots of data, so I want something generic); the location of the text depends on the data (i.e. I am not free to choose its location within my axes); and the "a little bit larger" is what I want to avoid, so that I do not have to think myself about how large my text will be relative to the scale on the axes. I will edit some of this into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you want to place the text but try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
plt.scatter(x,y)

minx,maxx = min(x),max(x)
miny,maxy = min(y),max(y)

plt.text(minx,miny, "This text goes outside the plot. If you have a longer text,\n you can do a line break.")
plt.text(minx,maxy, "This text is entirely outside the plot.")
plt.show()
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn2dA.png)

Answer (score -1):

The most direct solution that I would use would be to make the notes outside of the plot by using some other presentation method (like imagemagick) to add captions.